# Reactjs proxy [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request from localhost:8080 to https://localhost:8443/test UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https, proxy, webpack-dev-server

the proxy was working until i updated the node js on my pc so i can not started any more.

my proxy Configs look like:

```js
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
            proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'https://localhost:8443/test',
                pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }, secure: false, // had an expression which was resolving to true
                    changeOrigin: true,
                        headers: {
                "Connection": "keep-alive"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

the Error is coming when i remove the secure: false.
but when i have the tag(secure: false) i did not get any error but my app keep calling localhost:8080 and not https://localhost:8443/test

what i tried until now that i deleted nodes_module and package-lock.js
also i deleted the cache
then i installed again with npm install also npm update but no result
also i tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PRoblem was at IIS
my backend was there not rightly configured for the endpoint https://localhost:8443/test

so i did not get the right error just i saw in browser that the wrong linke is beeing called .

the fix was to rightly configure the https://localhost:8443/test in iss